# Dygraphs chart datapoints connected with "rectangular" line

Tags: dygraphs

i have a dygraphs chart and expecting my data points connected by a straight line. Instead i have a line like this:

[image]

And here is how (part of) my data looks like:

[image]

Has anyone ever had this issue?

Comment: I thought it is because of the consecutive duplicates. After i removed them, i still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the duplicates. After removing them the chart looks like expected.

[image]